# Sequentially numbering repetitive interactions in R

Tags: r, plyr

I have a data frame in R that has been previously sorted with data that looks like the following:

```
id creatorid responderid
 1         1           2
 2         1           2
 3         1           3
 4         1           3
 5         1           3
 6         2           3
 7         2           3
```

I'd like to add a value, called `repetition` to the data frame that shows how many times that combination of (`creatorid`,`responderid`) has previously appeared. For example, the output in this case would be:

```
id creatorid responderid repetition
 1         1           2          0
 2         1           2          1
 3         1           3          0
 4         1           3          1
 5         1           3          2
 6         2           3          0
 7         2           3          1
```

I have a hunch that this is something that can be easily done with `dlply` and `transform`, but I haven't been able to work it out. Here's the simple code that I'm using to attempt it:

```
dlply(df, .(creatorid, responderid), transform, repetition=function(dfrow) {
    seq(0,nrow(dfrow)-1)
})
```

Unfortunately, this throws the following error (pasted from my real data - the first repetition appears 166 times):

```
Error in data.frame(list(id = c(39684L, 55374L, 65158L, 54217L, 10004L,  : 
   arguments imply differing number of rows: 166, 0
```

Any suggestions on an easy and efficient way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `plyr`:

```
ddply(df, .(creatorid, responderid), function(x) 
            transform(x, repetition = seq_len(nrow(x))-1))
```

Using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, repetition := seq_len(.N)-1, by = list(creatorid, responderid)]
```

using `ave`:

```
within(df, {repetition <- ave(id, list(creatorid, responderid), 
                FUN=function(x) seq_along(x)-1)})
```

Comment: That's exactly what I had been trying to do for the last few hours. If I could give extra bonus points for showing multiple ways to do it, I would. Nice work.